# sencha touch set idProperty manually can't sync

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I set the model's `idProperty` manually?
For example:
Assume that the `idProperty` of `model` is `id`
There is one record:
This is my `Model`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.DataModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        idProperty:'myId',
        fields: [
          { name: 'myId', type: 'auto' },
          { name: 'number', type: 'int' }
       ]
  }
});
```

This is my `Store`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.DataStore', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
      model: 'MyApp.model.DataModel',
      autoLoad: true,

      proxy: {
          type: 'localstorage',
          id: 'datastore'
       }
  }
});
```

With the code above, when I add one record like:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("DataStore");
var code = { myId: 1, number: 233 }
store.add(code);// The record added to the store.data, when I saw it in the developer tools
store.sync();  // yes, there is no error, but also without any change to this store
```

How can I set this error? Because I see it's an bug in localstorage in `Sencha Forum` [Bug source](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?215424-how-to-set-id-field-manually) in 2012, I thought it would be fixed now.

### ---

And there is one other problem is:
The content of list is depend on the `store` it uses.
There is one list I use `DataStore`, Its code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SlideView', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'slideview',
    config: {
        itemTpl: Utils.Config.Templates,
        store: 'DataStore',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit',
            pack: 'right'
        },
        disableSelection: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'listitem',
                items: {
                    xtype:'panel',
                    tpl: Utils.Config.Templates,
                    data: Utils.Config.Templates.data,
                },
                minHeight: 60
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

How can set this xtype (now it's `listitem`) like other `items` which introduce by the `store` record?
Because no matter the style or event, they are not same.

Comment: You are adding `{ id: 1, sample: "some strings"}` but I don't see the `id` and `sample` fields in your model. Is that part of your design?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I'm sorry, the `id` means `myId`, and the `sample` now I change it to `number`

Answer (score 0):

If you set idProperty and you do not create your own implementation of how to use it, Sencha might use uuids. But as you are adding your own, I am not sure if this should be supported. Leave it to Sencha to add values to the idProperty key.

To grab the first item from a store simply use

```
var firstItem Ext.getStore('myStore').first(),
    data = firstItem.getData();
```

or in case you add the store to the list filter it to only the first item .... So many ways :)

To find out more about listitems please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.component.ListItem). If you need to set the listitem to another xtype you can set

```
defaultType: 'newXtypeToUse'
```

Usually this will be 'simplelistitem' or 'listitem'